# How can I see a git status showing renames?

Tags: git

When rebasing a change I notice Git printing the following after a "git commit --amend":

```
 11 files changed, 427 insertions(+), 2067 deletions(-)
 rewrite include/File1.h (71%)
 rename include/{File1.h => File2.h} (75%)
 rewrite dir1/File1.cc (86%)
 rename dir1/{File1.cc => File2.cc} (80%)
```

However, when I run git log -1 --stat afterwards it doesn't show the renames:

```
 include/File1.h           |  160 +------
 include/File2.h           |  166 ++++++
 partition/File1.cc        | 1081 ++--------------------------------------
 partition/File2.cc        | 1031 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Is there a way to see the renames without rebasing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try
`git log -1 --stat -M`
The `-M | --find-renames` flag instructs `git log` to look for renames. Similarly the `-C | --find-copies` flag will also look for copies.
Long-form options:
`git log -1 --stat --find-renames --find-copies`

If it's not finding the renames you want, you can also adjust the threshold. For example, `git log -1 --stat -M70%` will consider any new file that's at least 70% similar to a removed file to be a rename (the same applies to `-C` for copies). I believe the default is 50%.

If you always want this behavior, you can set the config variable `diff.renames`. If set to `true`, it will always detect renames, and if set to `copy` or `copies` it will always detect copies as well.

Comment: An extra bit of detail to help you remember: the M stands for "move", since moving and renaming are the same operation in the Linux world.